# Difference between 'db.collection' vs 'new mongo.Collection'

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Are there any differences (besides method 1 being async) between method 1 and 2 to obtain a reference to a mongodb collection shown below?

```js
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var db= new mongo.Db('blog', new mongo.Server(host, port, {auto_reconnect: true}, {}));
db.open(function(){
    //Method 1
    db.collection('articles', function(err, result){
        var collection1 = result;
    });

    //Method 2
    var collection2 = new mongo.Collection(db, 'articles');
});
```

Comment: Are you sure method 2 is sync? MongoDB should not create a collection until it has been touched in some way, i.e. adding data or creating an index. If it appears async I think that is node.js driver itself and not MongoDB doing it. Either I think the difference it calling it directly or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have only done it the "Method 1" way -- which works like a dream! (And, like you said, is async -- which is a must)